# How can I make a JavaScript function that takes two arguments (numRows, numColumns), and returns a 2D array with the correct grid values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, grid

Write a function makeGrid that accepts two arguments:

numColumns (number) - how many columns we want our grid to have

numRows (number) - how many rows we want our grid to have

makeGrid should return a two-dimensional array that represents a grid of the given dimensions.

```
`makeGrid(3,4);
  /* => [[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]]
   */`
```

I've tried multiple variations of the same code below, both complicated and simpler with the same results. It returns a grid with the correct number of columns and the correct number of rows, but it keeps returning the wrong cell values. I am beyond confused at this point so any other insight or depth into what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated!

```
`function makeGrid(numColumns, numRows){
  arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++){
    arr[i] = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < numColumns; j++){
      arr[i].push(j)
    }
  }return arr;
}`
```

Comment: You need to make your loops start at `1` (`= 1;`), and run up until `i`/`j` equals the row/cols values `<=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pushing `j+1` to the `arr` array eg. `arr[i].push(j+1)`.

**Working code:**

```js
function makeGrid(numColumns, numRows) {
  arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    arr[i] = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
      arr[i].push(j + 1)
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(makeGrid(3, 4))
```